# Selenium with Chromedriver: mimicking page_load_timeout

Tags: selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver, webpage-screenshot

Attempting to scrape webpages using Selenium webdriver, and screenshotting pages with flash elements by using chromedriver.

Downside is, Pages I scrape might encounter elements that never, ever load, and thus the script holds up waiting for a driver.get() command to finish loading. The following doesn't work with Chromedriver (I think due to a lack of support, according to the Selenium issue tracker)

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.set_page_load_timeout(15)
```

However, changing browsers does work (But I need to have the page's contents on chrome to be able to screenshot pages with flash content).

Is there any way I can emulate set_page_load_timeout, or disregard the get() method's fervent desire to finish loading everything before continuing?

Comment: Nope. I wrote some jangly code that timeouts alongside page loads and os.kills processes :(

Comment: @LeslieChong - I've been watching this with bated breath forever https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: fwiw, this is now implemented in the Firefox driver